# Node ssh2 server not accepting Objective-Git/libgit2 SSH connection

Tags: node.js, git, ssh, libgit2

I am trying to connect an Objective-Git/libgit2 app over SSH to a remote running [mscdex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2050455/mscdex)'s Node ssh2 server, using key pairs.

The libgit2 app can connect to `sshd` on the server and implement push.  It is implementing libgit2's `git_cred_ssh_key_new` and then `git_remote_connect`.

However, when the app attempts to connect to the ssh2 server, the server accepts the `ssh-userauth` service, but at the `ssh-connection` service the method type is 'none', rather than 'publickey'.

Alternatively, when I connect to the ssh2 server using git (rather than the app via libgit2), the ssh2 server accepts the `ssh-connection` service and implements method type 'publickey'.

So, I'm not sure where the problem lies: in the libgit2 implementation of the 'publickey' method type, or the ssh2 server falling through to method type 'none'.

Any pointers or help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

ssh2 server (example server):

```
new ssh2.Server({
  hostKeys: [fs.readFileSync('/Users/almccann/Sites/thenewpop/ssh2server/host_rsa')],
  debug: function (cfg) {
    console.log('debug', cfg);
  }
}, function(client) {
  console.log('Client connected!');
  client.on('authentication', function(ctx) {
    // ctx.method === 'none', no ctx.key
    if (ctx.method === 'publickey'
         && ctx.key.algo === pubKey.fulltype
         && buffersEqual(ctx.key.data, pubKey.public)) {
      if (ctx.signature) {
        var verifier = crypto.createVerify(ctx.sigAlgo);
        verifier.update(ctx.blob);
        if (verifier.verify(pubKey.publicOrig, ctx.signature))
          ctx.accept();
        else
          ctx.reject();
      } else {
        ctx.accept();
      }
    } else
      ctx.reject();
  }).on('ready', function() {
    console.log('Client authenticated!');
  }).on('end', function() {
    console.log('Client disconnected');
  });
})
.listen(22, '127.0.0.1', function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + this.address().port);
});
```

Comment: You should probably show relevant code to help others understand what you're talking about.

Comment: @mscdex see code samples, although this seems to be issue at framework / library level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `none` authentication method is basically what it sounds like, it's just an authentication method that allows clients access to the server without providing any kind of credentials or other information. That is why there is no `ctx.key` in that case.

Most servers will relay valid authentication methods back to the client when rejecting an authentication method, but this is not required (although some clients specifically rely on this, which is actually a bad thing). Assuming the ssh client *is* expecting this list, you can do something like this to signal you only accept `publickey` authentication:

```
client.on('authentication', function(ctx) {
  if (ctx.method === 'publickey'
      && ctx.key.algo === pubKey.fulltype
      && buffersEqual(ctx.key.data, pubKey.public)) {
    if (ctx.signature) {
      var verifier = crypto.createVerify(ctx.sigAlgo);
      verifier.update(ctx.blob);
      if (verifier.verify(pubKey.publicOrig, ctx.signature))
        ctx.accept();
      else
        ctx.reject();
    } else {
      ctx.accept();
    }
  } else
    ctx.reject(['publickey']); // <==============
});
```

Comment: Okay, great thank you @mscdex.  That's interesting that you pass list of accepted methods to reject.  At the method `none` state, is the client effectively polling the server to see what methods are accepting.  Assuming the server handled the case `none`, it would then move to highest priority type, which may be `publickey`?

Comment: Yes, when most clients request `none` they are doing so for two reasons: to be automatically authenticate with the least amount of effort (unlikely to happen for security reasons) and to find out what "actual" methods the server is allowing clients to proceed with. There is no defined/standardized order for the methods, but I would guess most clients that do use those method lists returned by the server typically start from left to right.